# The value of JavaScript prompt box is correct, still it is not performing an action

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a button that creates a simple random math question which the user has to solve it to proceed. However, even when I have typed the correct value, it is not performing the specified action. In order to clarify it, I have attached a runnable code snippet:

```js
function theFunction() {
  var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var userAns = prompt("Please solve this simple question in order to know that you are not a robot: " + num1 + "+" + num2);
  if (userAns === num1 + num2) {
    alert("Your answer was right.");
  } else if (userAns === null || userAns === "") {
    alert("Please type something");
  } else {
    alert(num1 + num2);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="theFunction()">Click here</button>
```

As you can see, if we type the right answer, the alert box should say "Your answer was right". However, if it is wrong, the alert box should show the correct answer. Even if I type the correct answer, it does not show "Your answer was right". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `userAns` is a string, `num1 + num2` is a number. `===` will never be true for different types.

Comment: `userAns` will be a string, and equality comparisons with strict type checking (`===`) will never return `true` when comparing across data types. Use `parseInt()` on the input value to properly compare using `===` or use `==` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user input returned by `prompt` is a string. If you want to compare it to a number, you'll have to convert one of them:

```js
function theFunction() {
  var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var userAns = prompt("Please solve this simple question in order to know that you are not a robot: " + num1 + "+" + num2);
  if (userAns === String(num1 + num2)) { // Here!
    alert("Your answer was right.");
  } else if (userAns === null || userAns === "") {
    alert("Please type something");
  } else {
    alert(num1 + num2);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="theFunction()">Click here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either convert `num1 + num2` to string or parse the prompt as integer as in this code:

```js
function theFunction() {
  var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var userAns = prompt("Please solve this simple question in order to know that you are not a robot: " + num1 + "+" + num2);
  if (parseInt(userAns) === num1 + num2) {
    alert("Your answer was right.");
  } else if (userAns === null || userAns === "") {
    alert("Please type something");
  } else {
    alert(`The correct answer was: ${num1 + num2}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="theFunction()">Click here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

"if (userAns === num1 + num2)" update this code into this "if (userAns == (num1 + num2))" and you can validate it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the prompt by default take value in a string so you can simply add +prompt and it will work fine +prompt convert string into number so if you do any equation it will work
check This out

```js
function theFunction() {
  var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var userAns = +prompt("Please solve this simple question in order to know that you are not a robot: " + num1 + "+" + num2);
  if (userAns === num1 + num2) {
    alert("Your answer was right.");
  } else if (userAns === null || userAns === "") {
    alert("Please type something");
  } else {
    alert(num1 + num2);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="theFunction()">Click here</button>
```